# How can I change Delphi's 'Run' and 'Add Breakpoint' shortcut keys?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, customization

How can I change the IDE keyboard shortcuts in Delphi?

I want to change "Run" from <kbd>F9</kbd> to <kbd>F5</kbd>
and "Add Breakpoint" from <kbd>F5</kbd> to <kbd>F9</kbd>

I'm currently programming Delphi at home and C# at work and these 2 shortcut keys are confusing because they are the opposites of each other!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a better solution for me because the Visual Studio emulation is not the same as my VS and can't be customised
and as Altar mentioned GExperts IDE menu shortcuts is not working with Delphi XE.

Using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) I remap the keys using this script:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class TAppBuilder
;Set breakpoint
F5::F9
;Run
F9::F5
;Step Over
F10::F8
;Trace Into
F11::F7
;Delete line
^l::^y
;Switch between form and code
F7::F12
;Find Declaration
F12::Send !{Up}
;Navigate Back
^-::Send !{Left}
;Navigate Forward
^=::Send !{Right}
;Duplicate Line
+Enter::^!+d
;Incremental Search
^i::^e
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than trying to use the OpenToolsAPI to remap keystrokes.  I want to use "shft+F4" instead of "F4" to `run to cursor`.  `BindingServices.AddKeyBinding()` will map "ctrl+F4" and "alt+F4", but I couldn't get it to map "shft+F4".  AutoHotkey made it very easy.  The footprint is next to zero and it's one less add-on to Delphi!

Answer (score 23):

@Kobus, you can map the keys to simulate the behavior of visual Studio IDE using the "key mappings" tab, located in tools->Editor options menu.

see theses images (Delphi 7)

[image]

[image]

Delphi 2010

[image]

Another option is install [Gexperts](http://www.gexperts.org/), and use the expert [IDE menu shortcuts](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?ide_menu_shortcuts.html), This expert enables you to configure any of the IDE menu shortcuts.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gexperts.org](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/ide%20menu%20shortcuts.png))</sub>

Comment: GExpert IDE menu shortcuts is not working with Delphi XE. XE will ignore the changes.

Answer (score 5):

I personally use [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/) which provides a Delphi keyboard mapping for Visual Studio plus a whole range of additional tools.  It's also free :-)

Simon

Comment: Yes I like DPack and use it a work! 
Coming from Delphi I love the the "Code/File Browsers" and "Numbered Bookmarks". And the "Collapse All Projects" and "Locate In Solution Explorer".
But I'm used to and prefer the Visual Studio keyboard mappings because I work in VS most of the day.