# How to debug without the F buttons?

Tags: debugging, keyboard-layout

How to debug on a laptop that has different Function keys?

On a PC those buttons work, but on my laptop they don't because, for example the <kbd>F9</kbd> key (which should run the program) locks the screen. The <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> keys do other things, too, like locking the touchpad. I start the program with the mouse, clicking the button in the RAD Studio that says "Run", but then when it reaches the breakpoint I don't know how to start moving to the next line.

Edit: The FN button helped me. I use laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 3

Comment: You would probably get a better answer if you mention the brand and model of your laptop.

Comment: You have to press the **Fn** key altogether which you won't find on a real keyboard - f.e. on a [Fujitsu Lifebook it's at the bottom left](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=isch&q=fujitsu%20lifebook%20keyboard). It works like **Shift** or **Alt** or **Ctrl**, altering the meaning of keys. Yes, it's horribly stupid.

Comment: The toolbar has "Trace into" (F7) and "Step over" (F8) buttons. They are just to the right of the Play/Pause/Stop buttons. The same commands are also found on the Run menu.

Comment: Isn't the IDE by now able to customize all key assignments? See also [How can I change Delphi's 'Run' and 'Add Breakpoint' shortcut keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2301302/4299358)

Comment: @AmigoJack Thank you very much it works with the FN button. Customizing the keys wouldn't have been useful for me, because I sometimes work in the office, where I use a pc and a keyboard that don't have a problem with the Function keys, and I sometimes work from home and I use remote desktop connection, so I wouldn't want to change the keys because I'm used to these already, and I don't want to have to change the keys everytime I go to the office and home.

Comment: Edit your question to include brand/vendor and model of your laptop (as suggested by @MartynA already) and I can add an actual answer.

Comment: @AmigoJack I saw his response, but since the FN button does the job I didn't think it's needed to add what I use but I will edit now for next people to see I guess if they ever have such problem.

Comment: That was only a comment. Take the [tour] to learn how this website works and why questions should have enough details and why answers are better than just comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [Lenovo *IdeaPad 3*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=lenovo+ideapad+3+keyboard+layout&tbm=isch) has (like also [Fujitsu's *Lifebook*](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=isch&q=fujitsu%20lifebook%20keyboard)) the additional [key <kbd>Fn</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key) on the lower left, which occurs for compact keyboard layouts (such as on laptops). Handle it like you would handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>: press and hold it down first, then the actual key you want to press.

In general multiple actions of a keyboard key are distinguished by their printed position:

- **bottom left**: the default action - have a look at f.e. <kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>8</kbd> or <kbd>Home</kbd>.
- **top left**: when holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> - this also explains why all letters are printed in uppercase. See also how you'd press <kbd>?</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd> or <kbd>:</kbd>.
- **bottom right**:

  - if you have: when holding <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> - on f.e. German layouts by this you achieve pressing <kbd>µ</kbd> or <kbd>€</kbd> or <kbd>³</kbd>. If you also have a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key then actions for for that are enclosed in a rectangle.
  - if no <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> is available, it is meant for holding <kbd>Fn</kbd> (and then actions are not essentially in rectangles) - that's how you finally can press <kbd>F9</kbd> and such, while the key's default action is device specific.
- **top right**: almost only encountered outside latin alphabets, when whole input method menus need to be used.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) for different layout examples, including [potential <kbd>Fn</kbd> positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#/media/File:Physical_keyboard_layouts_comparison_ANSI_ISO_KS_ABNT_JIS.png).